# Having the git local on a remote server?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using a remote server (which I access via ssh) to use the Matlab files and the big data files stored there. The Matlab files are used by other (selected) users, whereby the access is regulated to avoid overlapping work.

Now I want to use the company's git system to follow the changes of the .m-files. So I changed the directory to the remote directory, initiated git, and added files, committed and pushed everything to the remote gitlab repo.

The question is: How reasonable is it to have a local git repo on a remote server whose directories can be accessed by others? Can others use git from the same directory?

Comment: this question assumes a use of git that runs against its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It is reasonable if the access is read-only.

It is *probably not* reasonable if the users will be making changes in that same directory:

- Do you want users intermingling their changes? Then it's *maybe* ok. But this smells bad. It implies multiple users not even sitting next to each other making changes to a shared set of files.
- Is you're *only* using git for change history, and not *who* did what change, then it's *maybe* ok. But still smells bad (see above).
- If you are using git to track *who* did what change, **then it's *NOT* ok.**

  Have each user clone the repo on their local machine and use git as it is meant to be used.